# 'TeX capacity exceeded' even though I use externalization

Tags: pgfplots, externalize

I added the `-shell-escape` (or `-enable-write18`) option in my Texstudio because I have a lot of heavy data plots in my document. For now, I just hardcoded it in the Compile command

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

but I still get the following error

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. \end{axis}
```

Here you find a minimum example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside=semi]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm,left=2.5cm}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale= UK}

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={thick}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \input{V_MOSFET_coupling}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The V_MOSFET_coupling.tex file contains about 65000 lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think that with externalize you avoid memory constraints completely? You will still need to make sure that the memory is sufficient to produce this plot. You may want to consult section **6.1 Memory Limits of TEX** of the pgfplots (!) manual to see what your options for increasing the memory are.

Comment: I did what it tells me in the manual but still the same error. I inserted main_memory=90000000 save_size=80000 in the empty inf file which opened up after this command: initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex

Comment: This is an error that I encountered quite often, when trying to plot extensive data sets. It usually helps removing e.g. every other line from your data file. While this technically isn't your entire data set anymore in many cases there is literally no visible loss of data quality.

Comment: I am of course aware of this option. But in my previous work I could only downsample my data to a certain amount because I had a few very distinctive points which would have been filtered away if I would have downsampled my data too much. I used a separate empty TeX-File (with only the settings for pgfplots) and use externalize + LuaLaTex and imported the generated pdf in the actual document. It's an okayish workaround I think.